# How do i control brightness in Dell laptops under ubuntu 10.04 platform?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, dell-inspiron, brightness

I have bought a new DELL laptop( [Inspiron 5050](http://www.flipkart.com/dell-inspiron-5050-laptop-2nd-gen-ci3-4gb-500gb-ubuntu/p/itmd9pf6zyykzqr6?pid=COMD9PEWXCQDFHDT&ref=d9bfcd64-71f7-4cf7-b786-9386b3f1b23b) ). I am able to control brightness in windows 7 through f4 and f5 keys. Now i have installed ubuntu 10.04. The problem is that the function keys f4 and f5 are not working here. I have also tried combination of fn and function keys( f4 and f5 ).

What should i do now? Do i need to install any extra package to control the brightness in ubuntu 10.04?

Answer (score 0):

Do your other function keys work? Like the keys for volume control?

A few people seemed to have solved the problem by installing gnome-power-manager and uninstalling xfce-power-manager.

[This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1470763) thread may be of some help.

Comment: Yeah, function key for volume control is working.